# 'Update Information Is Outdated' related to failed installation of apt-fast

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, software-installation, apt-fast

I recently subscribed to Linux Format, and in the Aug. 2014 issue ('Fix Ubuntu') they recommended apt-fast to install software faster:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

The installation failed, and now I'm getting the red triangle stating my update information is outdated (with two 404 errors related to apt-fast). Also, it says I have no internet connection when trying to switch update servers.

I installed Synaptic to look for the failed install of apt-fast to delete it, but it's not listed anywhere. I also checked /etc/apt/sources.list, but there wasn't any reference to apt-fast that I could find.

So my question is how do I completely delete apt-fast (even if it failed to install), and will that fix the update issue? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus X201E netbook.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Rather than editing the answer into the question, please accept the posted answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PPA doesn't have the Trusty version uploaded yet, and because there are (or were) no Trusty packages, you're getting a 404 error.

As a short-term solution, you can either open up Software Updates and, for this entry, change `trusty` to `saucy`, or you can use [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/myppa).

If you want to delete that PPA, run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:apt-fast/stable`.